# Nominatim API (OSM) administrative informations

Tags: json, api, openstreetmap, nominatim, administrative

**How can I get administrative informations via Nominatim API?**

API serves final page with all details here (I need *boundary:administrative* data):

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?osmtype=W&osmid=650507914&class=highway

…but if I want to have it in json format (parameter `format=json`) I don’t get all information like in previous endpoint:

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?osmtype=W&osmid=650507914&class=highway&format=json

I was trying to use „[lookup](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Lookup/)” and „[details](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Details/)” endpoint variants but the result was the same.